# Default CSS-design, saving Dropdown Menu Selection as a Cookie with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, default

HTML:

```
    <select name="change" id="change">

    <option value="1">Design 1</option>
    <option value="2">Design 2</option>
    <option value="3">Design 3</option>
    <option value="4">Design 4</option>

    </select>
```

JS:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {

    var expires = "";
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

function readCookie(name) {

    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
    }

function chooseStyle() {

    var title = document.getElementById("change").value;
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
        createCookie("style", title, 30);

    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var a = links[i];
            if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 &&   a.getAttribute("title")) {
                a.disabled = true;
            if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
                }
            }
    }


function init()
{
var styleCookie = document.getElementById("change");
        styleCookie.onchange = chooseStyle;

    var style = readCookie("style");

    if (style !== null){
            document.getElementById("change").value = style;
        }
        chooseStyle();

 }
window.onload = init;
```

I've been trying to make a site where you can choose between four different css-designs through a dropdown menu and then it will be saved as a cookie or local storage so the design will be the same when you revisit the site.

I need some help to figure out, when you visit the page for the first time it's suppossed to load the default design (Design 1) which I don't think it does atm. Would really appreciate some advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your init you can just add an else:

```
if (style !== null){
    document.getElementById("change").value = style;
} else {
    document.getElementById("change").value = "1";
}
```